# How do I align my new btrfs default subvolume with the real root of my filesystem?

Tags: btrfs, snapshot

I rolled back my system by using

```
snapper rollback
```

Unfortunately this caused my current default volume to not be at the root of my filesystem anymore. As you can see in this screenshot:
[image: current state of my system]

The question is: How can I fix this? I want the current default-subvolume to stay the default subvolume, but I want it to be the new "root" subvolume, not a subset of my old default subvolume.

I found this: https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/UseCases#How_do_I_mount_the_real_root_of_the_filesystem_once_I.27ve_made_another_subvolume_the_default.3F
which I believe deals with this exact problem, but whenever I try to mount it using that command, I just get

```
mount: /dev/mapper/cryptroot is already mounted or / busy
   /dev/mapper/cryptroot is already mounted on /
```

Besides: Wouldn't I have to create some permanent mount (thinking about something like fstab maybe)?

edit: I fixed it. I  made an rsync backup of my current snapshot (18), changed the default volume to the root volume (5) and rebooted from a usb stick. Then I just rsynced everything from my external drive back onto my pc, rebooted and all was good.